# Pre-Commit Hook - Validate Filename

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks

im trying to validate a filename on first commit. 
In the repository i have this files:
  change1.sql
  change2.sql
  [...]

Users cant create files whit the same filename.
How can i validate this in pre-commit?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$SVNLOOK info -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" > /var/log/lastcommit$TXN.log
$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" >> /var/log/lastcommit$TXN.log
```

so lastcommit100-3f.log would contain:

```
root
2011-05-21 09:23:48 +0000 (Sat, 21 May 2011)
31
Meldung an ERM schicken.TASK-78
U   enexus-release-management/JavaSource/org/enexus/PreCommitServlet.java
```

Comment: THanks. But how can i block the commit when the filename is invalid?

Comment: You need to code your validator for each line of lastcommit$TXN.log.